Update table/form in Python while keeping specific output format
Trying to create a form for my organization using Python that has a section where traffic restriction information is structured in a specific way. A user would be asked to input most of the variables, which would then be display in a sentence-like output. A memo and other info is included on the form but I have that figured out.  Each form could have multiple traffic restrictions (I can get this to work with one restriction now).
I believe what I need to do is add rows to a table each time a restriction is "installed" or "removed." But there may be better ways to get the outcome I'm looking for. In the attached photo, as an example, I may need to add an item 3a with an empty row above it.
Example of output
Adding rows to a table's pretty straight forward, and I've gotten multiple restrictions to work when I've saved output to list first, but that's where the formatting goes out the window. This is how I have things set up now:
ITEM1 = (f'\t{IN_REM}:\n{item_no}\t{restrict_type}')
ITEM2 = (f'In {PD_dist}: for {trav_dir} traffic on {subject_st} at {street2}.')



Item

Location




{{ITEM1}}

{{ITEM2}}








DESIRED OUT
| Item       |    | Location                                               |
| ---------- | -- | ------------------------------------------------------ |
|    INSTALL:|    | In Townville: for northbound traffic on A St at B Ave. |
| 1a Stop    |    |                                                        |
OUTPUT WHEN COMING FROM LIST
| Item               |    | Location                                                 |
| -------------------| -- | ---------------------------------------------------------|
|[\tINSTALL:\n\tStop]|    | [In Townville: for northbound traffic on A St at B Ave.] |
|                    |    |                                                          |
I'm not sure if it's easier/better to use a list and put this all together after I'm done entering new restrictions or append the form as I go.  Any help would be appreciated.
